# Cross sell by website

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to get a cross sell by website.

In Magento 1.9 you only get the related products by one website but for example the product XXXX exist por website A and C and this product have related products distinct in website A and C.

How can I get it?

Thank you!.

Comment: What is the code you are using? Is it magento's default related product code or you are using your own code?

Comment: Is it magento's default product code